# Attempt string-to-real conversion in D without exceptions

Tags: parsing, type-conversion, d, phobos

Given an array of `string`, I want to find the first one that can be successfully converted to a `real` without using exceptions.

The only relevant functions I can see in Phobos are `std.conv.to` and `std.conv.parse`, but both of these will throw an exception if they cannot convert the string. I'd like to avoid exceptions because this is not going to be an exceptional circumstance for my use case.

C# provides `TryParse` for exactly this. Is there anything similar in D?

(of course, I could parse the string myself to determine if it is convertible to `real`, but it's non-trivial so I'd like to avoid that if possible).

Comment: What You can do is to extract the `to!real` part of the std.conv` with removed exception handling...

Comment: That's true. I assume I can take your response as "there's currently no way to do this in Phobos"? I will open an enhancement request for this if no-one has an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phobos doesn’t appear to have a way to do this without exceptions, besides `std.stream`. The problem is that `std.stream` seems to be deprecated. Here is an example using `sscanf` with `double`, though I don’t know how to do it with `real`:

```
extern (C) int sscanf(const char* input, const char* format, ...);

auto tryParseDouble(string input) {
    import std.string;
    import std.typecons;

    double result;
    if (sscanf(input.toStringz, "%lf".toStringz, &result) == 1) {
        return Nullable!double(result);
    } else {
        return Nullable!double();
    }
}

void main() {
    import std.algorithm;
    import std.range;
    import std.stdio;

    auto myArray = ["foo", "bar", "3.14", "42"];
    auto x = myArray
        .map!(tryParseDouble)
        .filter!(x => !x.isNull)
        .front
        .get;
    writeln(x);
}
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, however you may have missed the "without using exceptions" part of the question (constantly throwing exceptions isn't great for performance).

Comment: @PeterAlexander You can still use `readf` from `std.stream` or `scanf` from libc. Beware that `std.stream` seems deprecated.

Comment: Ok thanks. I figured that might be the case but thought it best to ask. I'll file an enhancement request.

Comment: @PeterAlexander I’ve added an answer without exceptions nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks, you can have a green tick and orange upwards arrow now :-)

Answer (score 0):

While sscanf() works, it is unsafe. I would open an enhancement request.

Try adapting the Phobos code, returning NaN instead of throwing.